# PHP explode not working propely with commas

Tags: php, explode

Why this code isn't working properly? The string should be divided by commas but it looks like it's divided by commas and spaces at the same time (or something like that).

```
// example $str
$str = 'Test Tset <test@test.com>, Foo Abc <foo@abc.com>, Another Email <anotheremail@mail.test>, email_wo_brackets@gmail.com';

$emails = [];
$email_list = explode(',', $str);

foreach ($email_list as $email) {
    if (!in_array($email, $emails) and strpos($email, '@') !== false) {
        $emails[] = $email;
        echo sizeof($emails) . " $email<br>";
    }
}
```

It should be:

```
1 Test Tset <test@test.com>
2 Foo Abc <foo@abc.com>
3 Another Email <anotheremail@mail.test>
4 email_wo_brackets@gmail.com
```

But it's:

```
1 Test Tset 
2 Foo Abc 
3 Another Email 
4 email_wo_brackets@gmail.com
```

Comment: Check the source code of the page, the browser interprets your email addresses as tags.

Comment: You're outputting to a browser which interprets '<' and '>' as tags. Use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: explode is working fine, it's the formatting of the output as mentioned above which is the issue.

Comment: yeah.. sorry guys my bad XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I fixed it already. The problem was in "<" formatting.

```
$email = str_replace(['<', '>'], '%%', $email);
```

**EDIT:**

```
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);
```

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars($email)`…

Comment: Oh yeah.. that's much better